# Play audio files one after another?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, ios5

I want to play audio files, but would like to play them one after another. I saw some things, but it does not really work. For example, I want that the sound continues, "ken" will play after the "lo":

```
 -(IBAction)LO:(id)sender{


    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;

    soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"LO", CFSTR ("wav"), NULL);

    UInt32 soundID;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);

    }

-(IBAction)KEN:(id)sender {
    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
    soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"KEN", CFSTR ("wav"), NULL);

    UInt32 soundID;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to go lower-level than system sounds. If it's simple, you can use [`AVAudioPlayer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html) and fire off the next sound each time you get the delegate callback that the sound has finished. Something like

```
#pragma mark - AVAudioPlayerDelegate

– (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)success {
    if (success) {
        // last sound finished successfully, play the next sound
        [self playNextSound];
    } else {
        // something went wrong, show an error?
    }
}

/*
 * Play the next sound
 */
- (void)playNextSound {
    // get the file location of the next sound using whatever logic
    // is appropriate
    NSURL *soundURL = getNextSoundURL();
    NSError *error = nil;
    // declare an AVAudioPlayer property on your class
    self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithURL:soundURL error:&error];
    if (nil != error) {
        // something went wrong... handle the error
        return;
    }
    self.audioPlayer.delegate = self;
    // start the audio playing back
    if(![self.audioPlayer play]) {
        // something went wrong... handle the error
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm very sorry I'm very new at this. I did not understand how I place the code in relation to the example of my code.
Can you give me an example about my example?.

Thanks a lot